# log rotation of catalina.out using catalina.sh on daily basis

Tags: tomcat, catalina.out

I just wanted to know that if I want to replace:

> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 &

to **rotate logs** on daily bases what should I replace it with. 
I understand that for:

> "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out 2>&1 &

we should replace it with this line

```
2>&1 |/usr/bin/cronolog "$CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina-%Y-%m-%d.out" &
```

But in later versions of **Tomcat** the line look like:

> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 &.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever do that, Tomcat is handling the logs itself. If you really want to change anything, read [Tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html).